# how to append text from edittext when the user inputs new texts in editext

Tags: android, android-edittext, append

I'm making a scrabble scorer app. And he user inputs the letter, in EditText, the score is computed and the word form and is displayed too...Now if another player is to add letters to the previous word the user should not reenter the letters in the word he just needs to add the letter from the previous word...say-- "inter" is previous word ... adding "n" should display "intern" adding again "ational" should display "international"....
Any help would be greatly appreciated...thankss a lot...

Answer (score 0):

```
 TextWatcher inputTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { 
            textview.setText(s.toString());
        }
    }

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){
}
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
}
};

editText.addTextChangedListener(inputTextWatcher);
```

Try this one

Comment: sir @Angel could you take a look at this ?
http://www.yogile.com/eqom4w3g#02430394l